# Sumar decimales

Tags: php, mysql, horas

Estoy tratando de sumar los total de horas que tengo en una tabla y no puedo resolverlo; este es el error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tabla horas

```
id(int) | idproyecto(int) | inicio(date time)   | fin(date time)      | totalhoras(decimal)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 11              | 2021-08-23 12:28:21 | 2021-08-23 14:31:21 | 2.05
1       | 11              | 2021-08-24 12:28:21 | 2021-08-24 14:31:21 | 2.05
```

horas.php

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$horas = $conn->query("SELECT SUM(totalhoras) as totalhoras FROM horas WHERE idproyecto = 11");
$rowhoras = $horas->fetch();

echo 'Total horas: '.$rowhoras;
```

> ### Objetivo
>
> Lo que intento obtener es el total de horas de cada proyecto.

---

> ### Actualizado
>
> Al utilizar esta consulta en la base de datos; `SELECT ROUND(SUM('totalhoras'), 2) FROM horas;`, me suma todas las horas.

Respuesta `VAR_DUMP`

```
var_dump($rowhoras);
// respuesta
array(2) { ["totalhoras"]=> string(5) "53.79" [0]=> string(5) "53.79" }
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Indica la API o herramienta de consulta que estás usando: mysqli, PDO u otra. Generalmente `fetch` tiene modos de asociación en base a los cuales deberás obtener el valor que deseas. Si depuras con `var_dump($rowhoras);`  verás lo que hay y sabrás cómo leer los datos. Tampoco se entiende qué tenga que ver esto con floatval o con round ¿? Ni siquiera se alcanza a comprender si la consulta satisface la necesidad planteada.

Comment: as intentado con `$rowhoras["totalhoras"]` o tambien con  `$rowhoras[0]`

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias, hice esta consulta en la base de datos `SELECT ROUND(SUM('totalhoras'), 2) FROM horas;` y me suma bien las horas, creo que el problema es que no estoy recorriendo con un bucle todas las horas. Al hacer un `var_dump($rowhoras);` el resultado es el array de las horas.

Comment: puedes hacer un dump, dd de la variable $rowhoras y agrega a tu respuesta el output???

Comment: @Sebastian agrega el ouput... a tu pregunta...

Comment: Mientras más claro seas en el planteamiento mejor podremos ayudarte. Falta por aclarar todo esto: 1. ¿Qué API usas (mysqli, PDO u otra); 2. ¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener exactamente: la diferencia sólo en horas o en horas, minutos segundos? Es importante que expliques ese punto, porque podría haber mejores opciones para obtener lo que necesites... 3. ¿Se trata de varias filas de resultado o de una sola fila? Si haces un dump de algo agrega a la pregunta el resultado del mismo. Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias a todos. Aquí edite la pregunta para ser mas claro. Disculpen por ello.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso ya edite la pregunta con la respuesta del `var_dump($rowhoras);`

Comment: @Sebastian al usar var_dump notaste algo?

Comment: Si, que los datos me los trae como `string` y en la base de datos tengo decimales. Pero no sé como cambiar o transformarlos

Comment: Puedes convertirlo con `(float)$rowhoras['totalhoras']`. ¿No te sería más útil la consulta: `SELECT idproyecto, round(sum(totalhoras),2) as totalhoras FROM horas GROUP BY idproyecto`?

Comment: @Bryro .......

Comment: @Sebastian me refería a que tu consulta se devuelve en un array al que estas accesando como string